# MILP - Adding a constraint renders solution feasible?

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I am using CBC solver in Pulp.

I have an MILP where I know a feasible solution exists.
Yet, I received a "Solution is not feasible" error.

I added a constraint "var_1 == var_2", which is part of the feasible solution I know exists and ta-dam, optimal solution is found.

How can this be?
Shouldn't the solver be able to always find a solution if one exists

I will note that all variables are either integers bounded between [1,50] or binary variables.

Thank you

Comment: Hard to diagnose without a lot more detail. Is CBC able to find an irreducible infeasible subsystem (IIS)?

Comment: Also if everything's integer and you just want a feasible solution, I would try a constraint program instead of a MIP.